# How to lock Iphone to a specific screen of app for some time, same like kids mode programmatically?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in which user gets alerts for Quran time. Now when user is in prayer i want to lock my device for that time same like enabling kids mode. How that can be achieved in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Apple hasn't released any kind of `Public` API to do so. And I'll never recommend to use the `Private` API's (if available in this case), cause it's could lead to reject your app.

In my knowledge I only knew how to prevent the phone from locking while your app is running.

> Objective-C

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES
```

> Swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

Comment: which private api is available?

Comment: I am not so much familiar with the Private APIs as we should used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add treatment for this inside the app, but unless the device is jailbroken, you cannot prevent the user from pressing the device's home button and leaving your app.

If you just want the user to stay on a specific screen of your app, you can disable user interaction (either by setting userInteractionEnabled = NO on the main ViewController's view, or by adding a transparent UIButton that will cover the entire screen, catch the presses and do nothing with them, as long as the payer is in session). You can also keep the screen from locking for that duration of time by using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

And setting it back to NO when the prayer is done (only if you choose to).

However, the user will still be able to leave the app by using the device's physical home button that will take him back to the home screen.